# What to name a registration landing page for most effective user acceptance

Tags: terminology, conversion, landing-page

I'm looking for advice and stats on what is the most user friendly naming conventions for a registration page. I'm assuming users are reminded of a spammy situation if they are giving up their email on a **"Registration"** page and perhaps even a **"Signup"** page.

Perhaps something like "Create a free account" would be best? But then what should the URL be for the page? /create-account/ ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's any current studies about this, but this is a really easy to set test, so I'd recommend you do your own testing and see by yourself.

Other than this, and coming from a marketing background, I think you should avoid other that *registration* (or something like this, including your option "create account"). If I see something like "start winning" I'll feel things are a bit shady. For the same reason, I'll avoid the "free" part in the URL.

Think about the process:

---

user gets to your site ---> user gets convinced and decides to register ---> user looks for a **registration** action ---> user registers

---

Now, as you can see, the goal is to get users to **register**, so, why would you try to add friction on this process? **You** want them to register, **they** want to register, so apply the KISS principle: allow them to register without any *gimmicky* tricks, **they want to do it, you achieved it**!

Comment: Thanks @Devin, nice insight. I'm still not convinced though!

Comment: well, then there's where testing comes handly ;) Just as a tip: I have a very simple and straight template system made in WordPress where I can change anything and everything in a couple clicks or text inputs. I use this sytem for quick A/B testing without using the real site. You might try somethign like this and see how it works. You could also use Zurb's Enroll for some relatively unexpensive testing